# Using keystore to generate signed APK

Tags: java, android, apk

Should I set a new Keystore for each app I build or I can use the same one existing for many apps ?
I created many keys when building my apps and now I'm confused either creating other ones or using old ones.

Comment: have you tried putting two apps with same keystroke sign on play store?

Comment: Yes I did that but I really don't know if I will continue like that or create keystores everytime. From the answer below I think I can continue using the same for many apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same keystore for n number of applications.

As you might know Android identifies each app with an UID. If all your apps are signed by the same certificate you can request android to assign same user id more than one app and inturn make them run in a single process and share the data.

From android doc android:sharedUserId

android:sharedUserId

The name of a Linux user ID that will be shared with other applications. By default, Android assigns each application its own unique user ID. However, if this attribute is set to the same value for two or more applications, they will all share the same ID — provided that they are also signed by the same certificate. Application with the same user ID can access each other's data and, if desired, run in the same process

Answer (score 0):

A Keystore is just an encrypted repository for your signing credentials. You can use the same Keystore for multiple apps if you prefer simplicity.

More about [signing your app can be found in the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).